# Why ACL is not working for new Action

Tags: magento-1.9, module, admin, adminhtml, acl

I have create **a custom admin action for a  custom admin controller** and have allow to this action for acl.

But till now, ACL is not working

Controller:

```
<?php
class Amit_HelloAdmin_Adminhtml_HelloadminController extends 
Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

 protected function _isAllowed()
    {

        $action = strtolower($this->getRequest()->getActionName());
        if($action == 'search') {
                 return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')
                    ->isAllowed('helloadmin/manage/search');
        }
        return parent::_isAllowed();;
    }


    //put your code here
    public function indexAction(){

        $_gotoSection =$this->getRequest()->getParam('gotosection');
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu($_gotoSection);
        //$this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Promotions'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Promo'));
        $this->renderLayout();

    }


   public function searchAction()
    {


    } 
    public function helloAction(){

        echo "how";

    }

}
```

**adminhtml.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <helloadmin translate="title" module="helloadmin">
            <title>Admin Theme</title>
            <sort_order>41</sort_order>
            <!-- action>adminhtml/helloadmin/</action -->
            <children>
                <manage translate="title" module="helloadmin">
                    <title>Manage theme</title>
                    <action>adminhtml/helloadmin/</action>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                </manage>
            </children>
         </helloadmin>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <helloadmin translate="title" module="helloadmin">
                        <title>Admin Theme</title>
                        <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <manage translate="title">
                                <title>Manage theme</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            </manage>
                        </children>
                    </helloadmin>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

My Question: why searchAction  url is  not working as i have already add 
  return

```
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')
                        ->isAllowed('helloadmin/manage/search');
```

Please help me to shot out this thing?

Comment: Well your ACL entry does not match the ACL declared in your XML file. Pretty sure it should be `helloadmin/manage` instead of `mysolutionadmintheming/manage/global`

Comment: lot of type mistake . Have modify it.. Now let me know  why `searchAction`  not working

Comment: Same problem you don't have an ACL matching `helloadmin/manage/search` you need to replace it with `helloadmin/manage`

Comment: that at adminhtml.xml,  i added `<helloadmin translate="title" module="helloadmin">
<title>Admin Theme</title>
<sort_order>40</sort_order>
<children>
    <manage translate="title">
        <title>Manage theme</title>
        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
    </manage>
    <children>
    <search translate="title">
        <title>Manage ddsw</title>
        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
    </search>
</children>
</children>
</helloadmin>` but not working

Comment: Have you try to assign role in `System->permission->role` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I am not able to find `mysolutionadmintheming` and `global`in your acl

I think you should try with

```
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')
                    ->isAllowed('helloadmin/manage');
```

please try and let me know

Comment: please check update question..

Comment: I am also not able to find `search` in your acl , and also instead of `Mage::getSingleton` try it with `Mage::getModel`

Comment: Have you assign the role for that user in `system > permission`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to use `helloadmin/manage/search` as an ACL entry you need to update your `adminhtml.xml` file, replace the following:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <helloadmin translate="title" module="helloadmin">
                    <title>Admin Theme</title>
                    <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <manage translate="title">
                            <title>Manage theme</title>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        </manage>
                    </children>
                </helloadmin>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

With

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <helloadmin translate="title" module="helloadmin">
                    <title>Admin Theme</title>
                    <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                    <children>
                        <manage translate="title">
                            <title>Manage theme</title>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <search translate="title">
                                    <title>Search</title>
                                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                                </search>
                            </children>
                        </manage>
                    </children>
                </helloadmin>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Comment: got.your point... Rapheal, will try shortly

Comment: sorry, i did not the result.. so  bad luck for me